# How to deal with deprecated values in (country-)code lists

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, database-design

Let's say we have a code list of all the countries including their country codes. The country code is primary key of the Countries table and it is used as a foreign key in many places in the database. In my application the countries are usually displayed as dropdowns on multiple forms.

Some of the countries, that used to exists in the past, don't exist any more, for example [Serbia and Montenegro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serbia_and_Montenegro), which had the country code of SCG.

I have two objectives:

- don't allow the user to use these old values (so these values should not be visible in dropdowns when inserting data)
- the user should still be able to (readonly) open old stuff and in this case the deprecated values should be visible in dropdowns.

I see two options:

- Rename deprecated values, for instance from 'CountryName' to '!!!!!CountryName'. This approach is the easiest to implement, but with obvious drawbacks.
- Add IsActive column to Countries table and set it to false for all deprecated values and true for all other. On all the forms where the user can insert data, display only values which are active. On the readonly forms we can display all values (including deprecated ones) so the user will be able to display old data. But on some of my forms the user should be able to also edit data, which means that the deprecated values should be hidden from him. That means, that each dropbox should have some initialization logic like this: if the data displayed is readonly, then include deprecated values in dropbox and if the data is for edit also, then exclude them. But this is a lot of work and error prone too.

And other ideas?

Comment: this is a temporal database now. Add valid_from and valid_to fields. If valid_to is null then it's active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I deal with this scenario a lot, and use the 'Active' flag to solve the problem, much as you described. When I populate a drop-down list with values, I only load 'active' data and include upto 1 deprecated value, but only if it is being used. (i.e. if I am looking at a person record, and that person has a deprecated country, then that country would be included in the Drop-downlist along with the active countries. I do this in read-only AND in edit modes, because in my cases, if a person record (for example) has a deprecated country listed, they can continue to use it, but once they change it to a non-deprecated country, and then save it, they can never switch back (your use case may vary).

So the key differences is, even in read-only mode I don't add all the deprecated countries to the DDL, just the deprecated country that applies to the record I am looking at, and even then, it is only if that record was already in use.

Here is an example of the logic I use when loading the drop down list:

```
    protected void LoadSourceDropdownList(bool AddingNewRecord, int ExistingCode)
    {
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            if (AddingNewRecord) // when we are adding a new record, only show 'active' items in the drop-downlist.
                ddlSource.DataSource = (from q in db.zLeadSources where (q.Active == true) select q);

            else // for existing records, show all active items AND the current value.
                ddlSource.DataSource = (from q in db.zLeadSources where ((q.Active == true) || (q.Code == ExistingCode)) select q);

            ddlSource.DataValueField = "Code";
            ddlSource.DataTextField = "Description";
            ddlSource.DataBind();

            ddlSource.Items.Insert(0, "--Select--");
            ddlSource.Items[0].Value = "0";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. I will probably make this method static and add dropdown as another parameter, but the rest is just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are displaying the record as read-only, why bother loading the standing data at all?

Here's what I would do:

the record will contain the country code in any case, I would also propose returning the country description (which admittedly makes things less efficient), but when the user loads "old stuff", the business service recognises that this record will be read only, and you don't bother loading the country list (which would make things more efficient).

in my presentation service I will then generally do a check to see whether the list of countries is null. If not (r/w) load the data into the list box, if so (r/o) populate the list box from the data in the record - a single entry in the list equals read-only.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with CollectionViewSource or you could just create a Public Enumerable that filters the full list using LINQ.

[CollectionViewSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx)

LINQ  The FieldDef.DispSearch is the active condition.  IEnumerable is a little better performance than List.

```
public IEnumerable<FieldDefApplied> FieldDefsAppliedSearch
{
    get
    {
        return fieldDefsApplied.Where(df => df.FieldDef.DispSearch).OrderBy(df => df.FieldDef.DispName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you still want to display (for instance) customer-addresses with their OLD country-code?
If I understand correctly, you currently still have 'address'-records that still point to 'Serbia and Montenegro'. I think if you solve that problem, your current question would be none-existent.

The term "country" is perhaps a little misleading: not all the "countries" in ISO 3166 are actually independent. Rather, many of them are geographically separate territories that are legally portions or dependencies of other countries.

Also note that 'withdrawn country-codes' are reserved for 5 years, *meaning that after 5 years they may be reused. So moving away from using the country-code itself as primary key would make sense to me*, especially if for historical reasons you would need to back-track previous country-codes.

So why not make the 'withdrawn' field/table that points to the new country-id's. You can still check (in sql for instance, since you were already using a table) if this field is empty or not to get a true/false check if you need it.

The way I see it: "Country" codes may change, country's may merge and country's may divide.

If country's change or merge, you can update your address-records with a simple query.

If country's divide, you need a way to determine what address is part of what country.
You could use some automated system do do this (and write lengthly books about it).
OR
(when it is a forum like site), you could ask the users that still have a withdrawn country that points to multiple alternatives in their account to update their country-entry at login, where they can only choose from the list of new country's that are specified in the withdrawn field.

Think of this simplified country-table setup:

```
id  cc  cn                     withdrawn
1   DE  Germany
2   CS  Serbia and Montenegro  6,7
3   RH  Southern Rhodesia      5
4   NL  The Netherlands        
5   ZW  Zimbabwe
6   RS  Serbia
7   ME  Montenegro
```

In this example, address-records with country-id 3, get updated with a query to country-id 5, no user interaction (or other solution) needed.
But address-records that specify country-id 2 will be asked to select country-id 6 or 7 (of course in the text presented to the user you use the country-name) or are selected to perform your custom automated update routine on.

Also note: 'withdrawn' is a repeating group and as such you could/should make it into a separate table.

Implementing this idea (without downtime) in your scenario:

- sql statement to build a new country-table with numerical id's as primary key.
- sql statement to update address-records with new field 'country-id' and fill this field with the country-id from the new country-table that corresponds with country-code specified in that record's address-field.
- (sql statement to) create the withdrawn table and populate the correct data with in it.
- then rewrite your the sql statements that supply your forms with data
- add the check and 'ask user to update country'-routine
- let new forms go live
- wait/see for unintended bugs
- delete old country-table and (now unused) country-code column from the "address"-table

*I am very curious what other experts think about this idea!!*

Comment: In my example, where should Serbia and Montenegro point - to Serbia or to Montenegro? :P

Comment: I see your point. But then, how about the data you already have? That suffers already from the same problem then? Say you have 10 records that pointed to 'serbia and montenegro'. How are you splitting them up to point to 'serbia' or 'montenegro'? By Postal-code?

Comment: Added detailed explanation to my idea

Comment: Added implementation suggestion

Comment: My business logic doesn't allow me to touch old data, so in my example this is not an option.